# Copy contents of Directories but excluding subdirectories in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, directory, copy

In Cocoa, is there any way to copy all the files in a directory without copying the directory's subdirectories along with them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to copy items in the directory conditionally based on the results of `NSFileManager`s [`-fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-CHDDDDJG):

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *files = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathFrom error:nil];

for (NSString *file in files) {
    NSString *fileFrom = [pathFrom stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    BOOL isDir;

    if (![manager fileExistsAtPath:fileFrom isDirectory:&isDir] || isDir) {
        continue;
    }

    NSString *fileTo = [pathTo stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    NSError  *error  = nil;
    [manager copyItemAtPath:fileFrom toPath:fileTo error:&error];
    if (error) // ...
}
```